# Failed to Start Kylin on hadoop cluster, no error found with check-env

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, apache-http-server

I am trying to install Kylin with Hadoop cluster which managed by Ambari. 
I am not able to start Kylin.

log as below:

```
*************************************************
[root@hadoop-app2 ~]# cd /usr/local/apache-kylin-2.6.0-bin/bin/
[root@hadoop-app2 bin]# sh kylin.sh start
Retrieving hadoop conf dir...
KYLIN_HOME is set to /usr/local/apache-kylin-2.6.0-bin
Retrieving hive dependency...
Something wrong with Hive CLI or Beeline, please execute Hive CLI or Beeline CLI in terminal to find the root cause.
[root@hadoop-app2 bin]# sh check-env.sh 
Retrieving hadoop conf dir...
KYLIN_HOME is set to /usr/local/apache-kylin-2.6.0-bin
[root@hadoop-app2 bin]# 
**************************
Ambari-server 2.7.3, 
hadoop cluster 3.1, 
hadoop services are running well,
also hive related as below:
****************************

[root@hadoop-app2 bin]# rpm -qa | grep hive
hive_3_1_0_0_78-jdbc-3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78.noarch
gvfs-archive-1.22.4-8.el7.x86_64
ranger_3_1_0_0_78-hive-plugin-1.2.0.3.1.0.0-78.x86_64
hive_warehouse_connector_3_1_0_0_78-1.0.0.3.1.0.0-78.noarch
oozie_3_1_0_0_78-sharelib-hive-4.3.1.3.1.0.0-78.noarch
hive_3_1_0_0_78-hcatalog-3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78.noarch
oozie_3_1_0_0_78-sharelib-hive2-4.3.1.3.1.0.0-78.noarch
atlas-metadata_3_1_0_0_78-hive-plugin-1.1.0.3.1.0.0-78.noarch
hive_3_1_0_0_78-3.1.0.3.1.0.0-78.noarch
libarchive-3.1.2-10.el7_2.x86_64
[root@hadoop-app2 bin]# 
****************************
```

Any action can I do to get more information about the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem just now and I found the solution:

1. I had to add my user (who runs Kylin) to the HBase Ranger policies through the Ranger UI
2. In Ambari go to Hive -> Configs -> Advanced -> Under 'Custom hiveserver2-site' add a property
3. Key: hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist.append
4. Value: dfs.replication|mapreduce.job.split.metainfo.maxsize
5. Type: Text
6. Restart Hive

If you don't have full rights on the Kylin folder you must take care of that too.

I recommend using the Log Search service (you can open it from Ambari), I found the error message in the Hive log file, the HBase error I got after I configured the whitelist successfully from the Kylin the Kylin CLI.